# Merging changesets to anonymous branch

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have a branch in HG repo (let it be `default`). I started an anonymous branch at some point, to make some tests (and added a feature, although I'm not sure yet what's the big adventage of having a feature, if using TortoiseHg). So far so good.

Now, the `default` branch got some bugfixes. I need them in my anonymous branch too.

What's the best way to merge or handle this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy the changes from the main `default` branch to the anonymous branch you would merge the default branch into the anonymous branch.

The problem with this is that you'd lose the extra branch so you'd need to note the current head of the main `default` branch if you didn't want the anonymous branch's changes in the main branch. To do this, you could tag the head of the main `default` branch before the merge.

Another option would be to mark it with a bookmark before doing the merge.

Then, if you need to make further changes to the main branch before permenamtly merging the two branches you would update to the tag or bookmark first.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it did the job and the explanation is really helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want integrate only *some changesets* after point of divergence from mainline into anonymous branch head, you can (depending on tree)

- rebase --keep
- graft

as it happens with named branches also

Comment: Not sure why it's downvoted, it sounds reasonable to me in some scenarios. I could use merging, as I needed to integrate everything from default branch. But I wonder what happens with grafted changesets if anonymous branch is integrated to default?

Comment: @Arek: "what happens with grafted changesets" - nothing. Same changes on both sides means *no changes to reflect in mergeset* effectively

Comment: +1 as I see this as a valid answer then. I only wish TortoiseHg somehow clearly indicated grafter changesets.

Answer (score 1):

You can just merge.  As you commit after the merge, your anonymous branch will continue until you're ready to push.

Comment: Thanks, this is same good answr as the mark one, the other one just explained it in details. +1

Answer (score 0):

I would just export the changesets from the default branch and import them into the anonymous branch.